# How to all columns of rows where multiple columns appear more than once

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a single table
I need to return all columns for rows where 4 of the columns are observed more than once.

I have a large table with data that has a unique ID, Several columns that together might repeat, and then either 2018 or 2019 as the year we got the data:

```
ID - Name - ZIP - Phone - Year Recorded 
4234 | John | 56473 | 555-555-555 | 2018
4234 | Tod  | 73746 | 556-556-556 | 2018
4235 | John | 56473 | 555-555-555 | 2019
4236 | Mary | 47384 | 577-577-577 | 2019
```

I want to select *  from [table] where  Name, ZIP, Phone are repeated and the year is 2019:

```
4235 | John | 56473 | 555-555-555 | 2019
```

I've used the following to at least show a couple of the columns for all the rows that those columns are the same for:

```
SELECT `Name`, `ZIP`, `Phone`, COUNT(*)
FROM VULNS
GROUP BY `Name`, `ZIP`, `Phone`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

John | 56473 | 555-555-555 | 2
```

The problem is that I need to include ID and Year Recorded but I cannot include them because they are not in the GROUP BY. IF I include those columns in the GROUP BY, then everything is unique and I get no results.

It's been a long time since I heavily used SQL and I think I am approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: I'm not sure what your definition of "unique id" is but I don't see one in your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM VULNS as v
WHERE v.YearRecord = 2019 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM VULNS as v2
              WHERE v2.Name = v.Name AND
                    v2.ZIP = v.ZIP AND
                    v2.Phone = v.Phone AND
                    v2.YearRecorded <> v.YearRecorded 
             );
```

That is, just return the rows from `2019` where the columns match in another year.

Answer (score 0):

Include `ID` in the `GROUP BY` list witihn the subquery, and use `( Name, ZIP, Phone, YearRecorded)` for collation with the subquery where `MAX(YearRecorded)` should be considered :

```
SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `ZIP`, `Phone`, `YearRecorded`
  FROM VULNS
 WHERE (`Name`, `ZIP`, `Phone`, `YearRecorded`) in 
(
 SELECT `Name`, `ZIP`, `Phone`, MAX(`YearRecorded`)
   FROM VULNS v
  GROUP BY `ID`, `Name`, `ZIP`, `Phone`
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```